# How solve -Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock! in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have got these issue, but can not get solutation

Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{44e26a30 com.india.screen/.CategoryList}

This problem get after adding these lines **( String numOfRows="select count(*) from  Holyplace_Tbl where State_id='"+stateId+"'";)** console nothing print after it

1. **Activity**

   ```
      public class CategoryList extends Activity{
          private TableRow holyPlaces,historicalPalces,beach,museum,hills,lakes;
          private int stateId;
         private AssetDatabaseOpenHelper assetDatabaseHelper;

          private Cursor holyplacesCursor,rowsCursor;


   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.category_screen);
       Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
       if (extras != null) {
           stateId=extras.getInt("stateid");
           System.out.println("stateid"+stateId);
       }
       holyPlaces=(TableRow) findViewById(R.id.holyPlaces);
       historicalPalces=(TableRow) findViewById(R.id.historicalPlaces);
       museum=(TableRow) findViewById(R.id.museum);
       beach=(TableRow) findViewById(R.id.beach);
       hills=(TableRow) findViewById(R.id.hills);
       lakes=(TableRow) findViewById(R.id.lakes);

        assetDatabaseHelper=new AssetDatabaseOpenHelper(CategoryList.this);
        assetDatabaseHelper.openDatabase();
       assetDatabaseHelper.openReadableMode();
        System.out.println("success.....!");

        String numOfRows="select count(*) from  Holyplace_Tbl where State_id='"+stateId+"'";

        System.out.println("rav  "+numOfRows);
           rowsCursor=assetDatabaseHelper.executeQuery(numOfRows);
           System.out.println("hjkdfhfh .............................."+rowsCursor);
           System.out.println("hj  hi .............................."+rowsCursor);
           if(rowsCursor.moveToFirst())
           {
               System.out.println("hi.........."+rowsCursor.getColumnCount());
               do{
                   int count=rowsCursor.getInt(0);
                   System.out.println("cu "+count);

                   System.out.println("cursor.. "+rowsCursor.getCount());
                   System.out.println("ccccc  "+rowsCursor.getInt(0));
                   System.out.println("jdjhfhf  "+rowsCursor.getColumnCount());

               }while(rowsCursor.moveToNext());

           }
           else{
               System.out.println("cursor not move");
           }

               rowsCursor.close();
               assetDatabaseHelper.close();
               System.out.println("no next value");


   }
   ```

   }
2. **AssetDatabaseOpenHelper.class**

   ```
   public class AssetDatabaseOpenHelper {
       private Context context;
   private SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabaseObj;
   private String database_name;
   private CreateQueries createQueriesObj;
   private MySQLiteHelper mySQLitehelperObj;
   private int database_version;

   private  String databaseName="TravelguideDb";
   private  int databaseVersion=3;
   public AssetDatabaseOpenHelper(Context context,String databaseName,int database_version) {
       this.context = context;
       this.database_name=databaseName;
       this.database_version=database_version;
   }



   public AssetDatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {

       this.context = context;
       this.database_name = databaseName;
       this.database_version = databaseVersion;
   }



   public void openDatabase() {
       mySQLitehelperObj = new MySQLiteHelper(context, database_name,
               database_version);

       File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(database_name);
       System.out.println("Assests"+dbFile.exists());
       if (!dbFile.exists()) {
           try {
               copyDatabase(dbFile);
           } catch (IOException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException("Error creating source database", e);

           }
       }


   }
      public void openReadableMode()
    {
    sqliteDatabaseObj = mySQLitehelperObj.getReadableDatabase();
   }
      public void openWriteableMode()
    {
    sqliteDatabaseObj = mySQLitehelperObj.getWritableDatabase();
   }
   public void close() {

   mySQLitehelperObj.close();
     }

   private void copyDatabase(File dbFile) throws IOException {

       OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dbFile);

       InputStream is = null;
       byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
       for(int i=1;i<5;i++)
       {
      is = context.getAssets().open("TravelguideDb.sqlite.00"+1);
        int length;
       while ((length=is.read(buffer))!=-1) {
           os.write(buffer,0,length);
       }
       is.close();
   }

       os.flush();
       os.close();
       is.close();
   }

      public Cursor executeQuery(String query)
     {
        Cursor outputCursor=  sqliteDatabaseObj.rawQuery(query, null);
   return outputCursor;
     }
   public void createTable(String tableName, String[] columns, String[] value) {
       createQueriesObj = new CreateQueries();
       String createTableQuery = createQueriesObj.CreateTableQuery(tableName,
               columns, value);
       sqliteDatabaseObj.execSQL(createTableQuery);
       System.out.println("Query" + createTableQuery);
   }
   public void deleteTable(String tableName) 
   {
       sqliteDatabaseObj.execSQL("Drop table " + tableName);
   }

   public void deleteAllDataFromTable(String tableName) {
       // truncate table
       sqliteDatabaseObj.delete(tableName, null, null);
   }
   public void deletePerticularRows(String tableName, String whereClause,
           String[] whereArgs) {
       sqliteDatabaseObj.delete(tableName, whereClause, whereArgs);
   }

   public Cursor fetchAllRows(String tableName) {

       return sqliteDatabaseObj.query(tableName, null, null, null, null, null,
               null);
   }
   public Cursor selectOnWhereCondition(String tableName,
           String[] columnsToSelect, String whereColumnName,
           String[] whereEqualsTo, String groupBy, String having,
           String orderBy) {
       return sqliteDatabaseObj.query(tableName, columnsToSelect,
               whereColumnName, whereEqualsTo, groupBy, having, orderBy);
   }

   public void updateRows(String tableName, String[] columnNames,
           String[] values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
           throws SQLException {
       if (columnNames.length != values.length) {
           throw new SQLException();
       }
       ContentValues contentValue = new ContentValues();
       int length = values.length;
       for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
           contentValue.put(columnNames[i], values[i]);
       }
       sqliteDatabaseObj.update(tableName, contentValue, whereClause,
               whereArgs);
   }

   public long addRecords(String TableName, String[] columnNames,
           String[] values) throws SQLException {
       long result = 0;
       if (columnNames.length != values.length) {
           throw new SQLException();
       } else {
           ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
           int length = columnNames.length;
           for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
               contentValues.put(columnNames[i], values[i]);
           }
           result = sqliteDatabaseObj.insert(TableName, null, contentValues);
       }

       return result;

   }
   ```

   }

Comment: Did you checked your loop ends in somepoint...

Comment: @TrackRuler nothing print after this line System.out.println("success.....!");

Comment: @mukesh i think contiounusly running its not out from loop ..simply first try to get single record remove the movetofirst and movetonext..in if condtion..and check and try ..fro all record

Comment: @TrackRuler i want to count only rows & that consists only one column.I excute query on sqlite manager.

Comment: @mukesh String numOfRows="select count(*) from  Holyplace_Tbl where State_id=' "+stateId+" '; use this query i think it will work

Comment: @TrackRuler it also have same problem

Comment: Are there any other places in the startup of your app where you access the DB? And what does `AssetDatabaseOpenHelper` do?

Comment: @CL. in my app I have access DB in 2 different places.AssetDatabasehelper is used to copy database from assest folder.

Comment: @CL. sorry, 2 different Activities

Comment: Go through this link , absolute discussion about your error .... https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/TfkPlN5b-ig

Comment: @TrackRuler it says it's warning message not error.But i have not seen contents of screen.

Comment: @TrackRuler it warning comes ater these lines  String numOfRows="select count(*) from  Holyplace_Tbl where State_id='"+stateId+"'";

Comment: Due to the busy and unreleased state of UIThread ur layout contentView might not be shown in the screen.So its never possible to tackle the problem unless until looking into the code.We need to know that what are the tasks you are loading from the beginning.Whether you may load something before setContentView() in ur onCreate() method, and that loading task may take some more times to finish or not released from loop. So in this case there may be no chance to reach the setContentView()... If you can , paste your oncreate() method and if anything you are loading before the activity creation...

Comment: @TrackRuler ok,give me some minutes.

Comment: Try your db actions in AsyncTask

Comment: @TrackRuler i try AsynTask ,screen shows but not get data from database.

Comment: So your database access are wrong in somewhere. Have to check database created or not , data available or not in the db, query applied is working or not. I suggest you to use ContentProvider and ContentResolver Model to access database. That is feasible to use Cursor Model queries...

Comment: @TrackRuler my database create in database & not give sql exception

Comment: I have tested your if and do while loop. its looping and gets ended in a point. So if your query works fine then there is no problem in the looping... Checkout again the query too...

Comment: if(rowsCursor.moveToFirst()) not execute properly